# Can a user have his own favourite questions list?

Tags: support

I want to keep a list of useful questions that I may need to refer again later. Is there a way to do so in stack overflow?

Comment: That's what happens when you click the star, you should be able to see it listed under your profile unless I'm missing something with the question. You could try it now on this post.

Comment: @PeterJ: Thanks. Tried on this post itself, it works!!!